# Construct a list of lists from command line

Tags: python, argparse

I am writing a small simulation in python, which is supposed to aggregate results in different ways depending on command line arguments.

Once the simulation has run and the `Simulation` object contains the raw results, I want to use the `Simulation.sample(list_of_objects)` method or the `Simulation.sample_differently()` method to generate some outputs for each specified sampler. `list_of_objects` should either be a `range(N)` or a list explicitly specified on the command line.

For example, I would like the following calculations to happen.

```
$ simulation --sample 5
[Simulation.sample(range(5))]
$ simulation --sample-objects 0 1 2 3 a
[Simulation.sample([0, 1, 2, 3, "a"])]
$ simulation --sample 4 --sample-objects 1 3 "b"
[Simulation.sample(range(4)), Simulation.sample([1, 3, "b"])]
$ simulation --sample-differently --sample-objects 1
[Simulation.sample_differently(), Simulation.sample([1])]
$ simulation --sample-objects 0 1 2 --sample-objects 3 4
[Simulation.sample([0, 1, 2]), Simulation.sample([3, 4])]
```

I thought I would do it as follows.

```
def parse_objects_to_sampler(object_strings):
    objects = []
    for entry in object_strings:
        try:
            objects.append(int(entry))
        except ValueError:
            objects.append(entry)
    return lambda simulation: simulation.sample(objects))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--sample", action=append,
    type=lambda x: lambda simulation: simulation.sample(range(int(x))))
parser.add_argument(
    "--sample-differently", action="append_const", dest="sample",
    const=Simulation.sample_differently)
parser.add_argument(
    "--sample-objects", nargs="*", action="append", dest="sample",
    type=parse_objects_to_sampler)

for sampler in parser.parse().sample:
    sampler(Simulation)
```

Unfortunately, the `type` constructor operates on each individual command line argument, not on the list of several of them generated for `nargs≠None`, so the approach above does not work.

What is the best pythonic way to achieve the behaviour sketched above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` should focus on testing the inputs and converting them to basic inputs. It accepts one string as input, and returns some object, or raises an error if the string is invalid.  To handle the items of a `nargs*` list as an aggregate you need to process later, after parsing.

The Pythonic way (or in general good programming) is to break the task into pieces.  Use `argparse` to just parse the inputs, and subsequent code to construct the final list of `simulation` objects.

For example, I think this parser will accept all of your inputs (I haven't tested it):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--sample", type=int, action='append')
parser.add_argument("--sample-differently", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("--sample-objects", nargs="*", action="append")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The focus is on accepting an integer with `--sample`, a list of strings with `--sample-objects` and a True/False value with `--sample-differently`.

Then I can construct the list of ranges and `simulation` objects from those arguments (again not tested):

```
alist = []
if args.sample_differently:
    alist.append(Simulation.sample_differently())
for i in args.sample:
    # is a number
    alist.append(Simulation.sample(range(i)))
for i in args.sample_objects:
    # i will be a list of strings
    def foo(i):
        # conditionally convert strings to integers
        res = []
        for j in i:
            try:
                j = int(j)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        res.append(j)
        return res
    alist.append(Simulation.sample(foo(i))
```

If I've done things right `alist` should match your desired lists.

You could create a custom Action class that would perform this kind of addition with the `Simulation.sample`.  The Action gets the whole list as `values`, which it can process and add to the `namespace`.  But it doesn't save any coding compared to what I outlined.

===============

This pair of definitions might fix your '--samples-objects' argument:

```
def intorstr(astr):
        # conditionally convert strings to integers
        try:
            astr = int(astr)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return astr

class SamplesAction(argparse._AppendAction):
    # adapted from _AppendAction
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
         values = Simulation.sample(values)
         items = _copy.copy(_ensure_value(namespace, self.dest, []))
         items.append(values)
         setattr(namespace, self.dest, items)

parser.add_argument("--sample-objects", nargs="*", 
    action=SamplesAction, dest="sample", type=intorstr)
```

I'm ignoring the reasons why you are using `lambda simulation: simulation....`.  I think it would be less confusing if you rewrote that as a function or class definition.  Too many `lambdas` cloud the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think someone with more experience than me could talk about "most pythonic", but the way I would approach this is to accept a CSV string and then use the `parse_objects_to_sampler` function to split the string and do further logic.

So:

```
def parse_objects_to_sampler(input_string):
object_string = input_string.split(",")

objects = []
for entry in object_strings:
    try:
        objects.append(int(entry))
    except ValueError:
        objects.append(entry)
return lambda simulation: simulation.sample(objects))
```

Then you would call, for example:

```
simulation --sample-objects "0,1,2,3,a"
```

Hopefully this should get the result you want!